# ReCapcha Problems

Tags: php, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I have setup a [Piwallet](https://github.com/johnathanmartin/piWallet) and it needs a Recapcha v2 Key but when I try to login after providing the correct key I get this in the debug screen 
and it reads:

```
 [:error] [pid 7405] [client 181.123.31.124:59758] PHP Notice: Undefined index: g-recaptcha-response in /var/www/html/index.php on line 312
```

and that line reads:

```
 $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]);
```

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://github.com/johnathanmartin/piWallet/issues/93).

Comment: i know but how do i fix it